# Write csv or table variables to file

Tags: r

Lets say I have a file like this:

```
a b c d
2 3 4 5
9 8 7 4
5 7 8 4
```

I would like to export column `a` and `c` but nothing else.

Can I do a version of `write.csv` or `write.table`

e.g. `write.csv(myobject$a && myobject$b, file="outfile.csv")`

Comment: Write this instead: `myobject[,c("a","b")]`?

Comment: I will accept this as an answer but can you skip the row number in the output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work

```
write.csv(myobject[,c("a","b")], file="outfile.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

The brackets in `myobject[rows,cols]` select rows and columns of a data frame or matrix. If the rows argument is left empty, all rows are returned; and similarly for the "cols". A vector can be used to select multiple rows or columns. In this case, we're selecting all rows (because that part is blank) and columns "a" and "b".

The `row.names=FALSE` option prevents rownames from being printed. In some cases, you might want to keep them, of course.